# Error when doing 2 inner joins in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am doing two inner joins:

```
use SalesDWH
go


select COUNT([specimen id])  as [count],[practice name],qlmlismapping.[mlis practice id],[practice code],[Requesting Physician]
from quicklabdump a
inner join qlmlismapping b
on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
inner join PracticeandPhysician c
on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME)
where [DATE entered] between '12/1/2011' and '12/31/2011'
group by quicklabdump.[practice name],qlmlismapping.[mlis practice id],[practice code],[Requesting Physician]
order by [count] desc
```

and getting this error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "quicklabdump.practice name" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
The multi-part identifier "qlmlismapping.mlis practice id" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "qlmlismapping.mlis practice id" could not be bound.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the join incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the same aliases as your JOIN

```
select 
       COUNT([specimen id]) as [count],
       [practice name],
       b.[mlis practice id],
       [practice code],
       [Requesting Physician]
from 
     quicklabdump a
     inner join 
     qlmlismapping b on (b.[quiklab practice code] = a.[practice code])
     inner join 
     PracticeandPhysician c on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME)
where 
     [DATE entered] between '12/1/2011' and '12/31/2011'
group by 
     a.[practice name], 
     b.[mlis practice id],
     [practice code],
     [Requesting Physician]
order by 
     [count] desc
```

Some notes though

- qualify all columns
- use meaningful aliases (qld, qlm, pap etc)
- use ISO dates yyyymmdd
- Try to use column names without spaces

Answer (score 4):

You can't reference `qlmlismapping` etc in the rest of your query as you have hidden it with an alias so that is not an exposed correlation name.

You need to use the alias name instead of the base table name everywhere except from where the alias is actually defined.